# I want to make this table as Scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDMiR.jpg) Hii i want to make this screen scrollable there are certain tables i have created using linear layout but i have tried everything but cant find any solution.I used frame layout inside their is an linear layout so while running this on small screen it gets hide.I have tried add scroll view but its didnt work please help me to fix it out.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_down"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="8.8">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.6">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="14dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".8"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Quantity"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".9"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Hour Multiplier"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".7"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Shramanand Hours"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.6"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Courses/Camps"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".8"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtCount1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="3"
                            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                            android:hint="__"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".9"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtHours1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" x 10"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".7"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtTotalHours1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.6"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="1 Day Test including Machine Test"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".8"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtCount2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="3"
                            android:hint="__"
                            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".9"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtHours2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="x 6"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".7"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtTotalHours2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.6"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Manashakti Varganidar"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".8"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtCount3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="3"
                            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                            android:hint="__"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".9"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtHours3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="x 5"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".7"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtTotalHours3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button_bg"
                    android:text="Next" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>**
```

Comment: what was the error after adding scrollview? scrollview should work fine

Comment: the screen was getting shrink @NullByte08

Answer (score 0):

Add Scroll View with **android:fillViewport="true"** Attribute in Layout

And also add in menifest to resolve edittext shrink issue

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Try This Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="8.8">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Quantity"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Hour Multiplier"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Shramanand Hours"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Courses/Camps"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtCount1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="3"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:hint="__"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHours1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" x 10"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTotalHours1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="1 Day Test including Machine Test"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtCount2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="3"
                        android:hint="__"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHours2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="x 6"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTotalHours2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Manashakti Varganidar"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtCount3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="3"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:hint="__"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHours3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="x 5"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTotalHours3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="Next" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Check text not null**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text1=edtCount1.getText().toString();
            String text2=edtCount2.getText().toString();
            String text3=edtCount3.getText().toString();
          if(!isNullOrEmpty(text1)||!isNullOrEmpty(text2)||!isNullOrEmpty(text3)){
              //Add your executable code here
          }else {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Add All Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

        }
    });

}

public  boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str){
    return str==null || str.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Here the issue m facing now is while clicking on edittext it shrink all the edittext on top @Android Geek

Comment: Suppose there are five editext if one is filled than it should proceed and if everything is empty than give error can you send me the condition to chcek this